# Jquery: Zoomed image not show correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code from a plug in.  This is a Picture Zoomer, and have set the image width to 100%; and height to 320px.  They have passed these values as parameters.  The default value of the width was 320px.  I then converted this width to 100%. 
The problem is, that after converting the width to percentage (since i'm  building it in a responsive environment), 1. the zoomed image is not showing in its full width, and 2. When I hover the cursor over the image, i have to move to the far left of the image in order to see the preview.  Any help in this regard would be much appreciated. Here is the code snippet.

```
;(function($){
    $.fn.picZoomer = function(options){
        var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.picZoomer.defaults, options), 
            $this = this,
            $picBD = $('<div class="picZoomer-pic-wp"></div>').css({'width':opts.picWidth+'%', 'height':opts.picHeight+'px'}).appendTo($this),
            $pic = $this.children('img').addClass('picZoomer-pic').appendTo($picBD),
            $cursor = $('<div class="picZoomer-cursor"><i class="f-is picZoomCursor-ico"></i></div>').appendTo($picBD),
            cursorSizeHalf = {w:$cursor.width()/2 ,h:$cursor.height()/2},
            $zoomWP = $('<div class="picZoomer-zoom-wp"><img src="" alt="" class="picZoomer-zoom-pic"></div>').appendTo($this),
            $zoomPic = $zoomWP.find('.picZoomer-zoom-pic'),
            picBDOffset = {x:$picBD.offset().left,y:$picBD.offset().top};


        opts.zoomWidth = opts.zoomWidth||opts.picWidth;
        opts.zoomHeight = opts.zoomHeight||opts.picHeight;
        var zoomWPSizeHalf = {w:opts.zoomWidth/2 ,h:opts.zoomHeight/2};


        $zoomWP.css({'width':opts.zoomWidth+'px', 'height':opts.zoomHeight+'px'});
        $zoomWP.css(opts.zoomerPosition || {top: 0, left: opts.picWidth+30+'px'});

        $zoomPic.css({'width':opts.picWidth*opts.scale+'px', 'height':opts.picHeight*opts.scale+'px'});


        $picBD.on('mouseenter',function(event){
            $cursor.show();
            $zoomWP.show();
            $zoomPic.attr('src',$pic.attr('src'))
        }).on('mouseleave',function(event){
            $cursor.hide();
            $zoomWP.hide();
        }).on('mousemove', function(event){
            var x = event.pageX-picBDOffset.x,
                y = event.pageY-picBDOffset.y;

            $cursor.css({'left':x-cursorSizeHalf.w+'px', 'top':y-cursorSizeHalf.h+'px'});
            $zoomPic.css({'left':-(x*opts.scale-zoomWPSizeHalf.w)+'px', 'top':-(y*opts.scale-zoomWPSizeHalf.h)+'px'});

        });
        return $this;

    };
    $.fn.picZoomer.defaults = {
        picWidth: 100,
        picHeight: 320,
        scale: 2.5,
        zoomerPosition: {top: '0', left: '350px'}
        /*,
        zoomWidth: 320,
        zoomHeight: 320*/
    };
})(jQuery);



[enter image description here][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to play with this plugin, and I hope this is the result you are looking for.

I get the original plugin and change only the Default values for "scale" and "zoomerPosition" but it is not crucial for the change.

```
$.fn.picZoomer.defaults = {
    picWidth: 320,
    picHeight: 320,
    scale: 5, //<--- THIS
    zoomerPosition: {top: '350px', left: '0px'} //<--- THIS
    /*,
    zoomWidth: 320,
    zoomHeight: 320*/
};
```

The basic concept is to pass the correct width in pixels to the plugin. And using responsive I opted for the resize via Jquery, because the plugin forces the pixel dimensions, and the percentage becomes problematic for the zoom coordinates.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.picZoomer').picZoomer({
        picWidth: $(this).width()
    });
});


var clrTimeout;
$(window).resize(function(){
  clearTimeout(clrTimeout);
    clrTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
        $('.picZoomer').html($('.imgToSave'));
        $('.picZoomer').picZoomer({
            picWidth: $(this).width()
        });
  }, 200);
});
```

The timeout is useful to avoid overloading the resize calls. The last problem that remains is the aspect ratio.

[This is the JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/5n7xbonz/1/)

Hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks Baro! Woks like a charm :)